# Apply a function to range of multiple columns in a Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, arguments

Can you please tell me how i can use range of columns like
`x['D'] :x['A']` instead of listing all columns as argument to function one by one in below?

```py
df.loc[:,'F']=df.apply(lambda x: my_function(x['D'],x['C'],x['B'],x['A']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try do something like this:

```
df.loc[:,'F']=df.apply(lambda x: my_function(*df.columns.difference(['F'])), axis=1)
```

if your columns are in order you can slice like this:

```
df.loc[:,'F']=df.apply(lambda x: my_function(*df.iloc[:,1:4])), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Were you looking for something like this?

```
df.loc[:,'F']=df.apply(lambda x: my_function(x.loc['D':'A']), axis=1)
```

If you need the parameters to be a list of columns and not a dataframe:

```
df.loc[:,'F']=df.apply(lambda x: my_function([x for x in x.loc['D':'A']]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a dataframe like this

```
    E   D   C   B   A
______________________

0   8   9   9   6   1
1   8   4   1   4   3
2   0   4   6   9   3
```

And you want to apply some function `func` to columns `D` to `A`, you can try

```py
def func(x):
    return sum(x[1:])

df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

**output**

```
0    25
1    12
2    22
dtype: int64
```